# Word for- something that someone uses and then exchanges it

Tags: single-word-requests, recurring-events

I need the word for naming my new business. My business involves persons especially ladies to come and deposit their (single)ornament+reasonable money in return for different design of ornaments of similar weight 4-5 times an year.

So the word which you may suggest can be put in the business name either as the whole name, or as *not* a legit word but as a word which is signifying the meaning of business by including the part of the word, or by clubbing it with a **hinglish** word. 
You only **suggest me** the word which-
1)**is signifying the meaning of exchange
2)happens 4/5 times a year
3)probably relates to jewelry which is left idle as a NPA
4)probably relating to the attitude of women of not wearing the same jewelry again & again.**

**Your job** is to suggest a single word for the functions(listed above) that the business is performing. Then its my job to restructure that word to name the business.

Comment: Object of an [operating lease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_lease). Self explanatory, not very catchy :)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is not the community for naming service. You'd better edit your question getting rid of all business-related sentences and focusing on English Language and its Usage. What you are asking is not clear. The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: A bit childish, but that might not be a problem for a catchy commercial context: [*One time there was this little brat of a kid, in the year above me, who **wanted one of my swapsies,** but hadn't any swaps of his own that I needed.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22one+of+my+swapsies%22)

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about a pawn shop.

Comment: (But your question is very unclear.)

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: It sounds like you're suggesting something along the lines of a combo pawn shop and rental service, specializing in jewelry.  And Fumble Fingers's suggestion of "swap" as a term might also work in there.

Answer (score 0):

The word **lease** comes to mind:

**lease**-
to grant the temporary possession or use of(lands, tenements, etc.) to another, usually for compensation at a fixed rate; let;

You could also use **rent** or **loan** though.

Example:

She **leased** some jewelry in honor of the wedding, and returned it a few weeks later.

Answer (score 0):

There is a term that has achieved some currency in the last decade or so that might be helpful in your situation: **"Re-gifting."** While not a term I would likely use, it is now widely understood to mean the following:

"Regiving differs from straightforward giving in that goods are not acquired specifically for donation. Typically, goods that have been received as a gift are offered to others, unbeknown to them that it was originally a gift to the person offering it. Often the motives are principally charitable but also includes giving items which are surplus to one's needs."

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regift